# Restricted Stock Units (RSUs) - Choose to defer taxes at vesting?

Tags: income-tax

I have some RSUs that will vest next year. I plan to contribute to an education fund for each of my kids. From what I've read, it sounds like the amount at vesting is considered ordinary income, while any gains/losses between the time of vesting and selling is considered short- or long-term capital gains/losses (based on price sold vs price basis at vesting, and depending on whether the positions were held for less than or more than a year).

**First**, is all of the above correct?

**Second**, can I choose to defer the taxes (rather than "sell to cover") until the end of the year when I do my normal income taxes, so that I can take all of the money from the sale and dump it into educations funds?

**Finally**, am I correct in understanding that if I can not "sell to cover" and defer the taxes until the end of the year, I won't actually have to pay any taxes on the income portion if I invest all of it into an education fund (or traditional IRA, etc)? I would only pay taxes on the short-term capital gains on the difference between the vesting price and the sales price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of income vs capital gains.

I would check with your benefits department to be sure, but in my experience there's not an option to opt-out of tax deductions from "bonus" income, whether in RSUs or cash.

Another way to deal with the withholding if you plan to put the money from the RSUs in a tax-deferred vehicle is to just reduce withholdings on your *normal*  pay to compensate. So if you have, say, 4 allowances now, you could up that to 8 to reduce your withholdings for the rest of the year. When you file your taxes, the *total* income and amount withheld is all that matters, so you'll be in the same spot either way.

You can use the [IRS Withholding calculator](https://apps.irs.gov/app/withholdingcalculator/) to see how many allowances you need or look at the [withholding tables](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/2018-withholding-tables-now-available) to get as close as you can. Or just leave everything as-is and expect a big refund check next year :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I just realized there is no federal tax deduction for contributions to an education fund, so it may not even matter now. :/ I may have to pay that anyway, because I want this money to go towards college.

Comment: Depending on your state, you can get a _state_ tax deduction for contributing to a 529, and both _grow_ tax-free, so there still may be some benefit.